# Organizing Info Directory Node

Tags: customize, info

When I open the Emacs info reader, the top directory node is really cluttered.  It's difficult enough to navigate that it puts me off from using it.  There are a few things that I can't figure out how to do that would simplify my life a great deal:

1. Sorting by name. The entries seem to be sorted according to the order they are added, which means that an entry starting with Z comes before an entry starting with A if it is in a directory that comes earlier in `Info-directory-list`.  Can I change this so that I can browse in a sane manner?
2. Change fill column.  I understand there are complexities with hidden text, but the narrow fill column wastes a lot of vertical space.  I see `Info-refill-paragraphs` but this doesn't do what I expect (or anything at all that I can see).
3. Hide or reorganize entries.  I understand the headings are set in the actual info files on my machine, but is there a way to modify this without editing each file?  It's frustrating when I don't know if something will appear in "individual utilities" or "utilities" or "gnu utilities" or "network applications" or "basics" or "software development".

Comment: Those are great ideas! However, I don't think any of that is supported by Texinfo. All such formatting is done either by the author of the node (when they write the file), or during the installation process (i.e., with `install-info`).

Comment: @Tyler Thanks for the info. I didn't realize that the directory node depended on Texinfo's output directly.  Is it a static file somewhere that is then rendered by Info?  If so, maybe I could accomplish some of what I want outside of Emacs.

Comment: You have the source code, so you can certainly re-organize your info files however you like, and Emacs has tools to help you do so. But it's not something you can do dynamically as a user. The Texinfo and install-info nodes will get you started, if you're motivated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The top-level `dir` content of Info is not from a static file. See function `Info-insert-dir` in `info.el`.

   You can do `C-x C-q` to make the buffer writable, then select a set of lines and do `M-x sort-lines`, to sort by the manual name.

   You can do the same thing programmatically, if you want.
2. Changing `fill-column` won't help. As @Tyler suggested, that formatting is done beforehand.
3. You can hide selected text using text property `invisible`.  But I don't quite understand the last sentence of your #3. Can you elaborate on it? What is the problem you want to solve there?

Comment: Thanks, I think you've answered this as well as it can be.  I didn't realize so much of it relied on work done by texinfo.  As for my third question, I'm talking about the categories set in the info files as `INFO-DIR-SECTION`.  There doesn't seem to be any systematic way for people to choose these and so it ends up quite scattered.

Answer (score 2):

I hesitate to post this as an answer, because it specifically does *not* apply to the top-level `dir` node of Info.  But it is so close in other respects that I hope it might help, and it is a bit long for a comment.

---

If you use library [Info+](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/InfoPlus) then you can do what you describe and more, for any number of Info manuals. (But it does not help with the top-level `dir` node.)

If you hit **`O`** in a manual then the manual is cloned as an *editable, outline-enabled table of contents* (TOC).

This is similar to the standard command `Info-toc` (bound to `T`), but the buffer is in `outline-minor-mode`. Also, there is no redundancy, by default: each TOC entry is listed only once, not multiple times. (This is controlled by option `Info-toc-outline-no-redundancy-flag`.)

You can have any number of such TOCs, for the same manual or for different manuals.

Outline minor mode lets you hide and show, and promote and demote, various parts of the TOC tree for a manual. And since the TOC is editable you can make other changes to it: *sort* parts of it, *delete* parts of it, *duplicate* parts of it, move parts around in an ad hoc way, and so on.

Especially when combined with `Info-persist-history-mode`, command `Info-make-node-unvisited` (`C-x DEL`), and Info+ bookmarking enhancements (e.g., special link highlighting and persistently tracking the number of visits per node), `Info-toc-outline` gives you a way to organize access and visibility of a manual’s nodes, to reflect how you use it.

(But it does not change the formatting of ordinary Info nodes you visit. As I indicated in my other answer, changing the `fill-column` has no effect.)

HTH.